# ExcelFile Vs. read_excel in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm diving into pandas and experimenting around. As for reading data from an Excel file. I wonder what's the difference between using ExcelFile to read_excel. Both seem to work (albeit slightly different syntax, as could be expected), and the documentation supports both. In both cases, the documentation describes the method the same: "Read an Excel table into DataFrame" and "Read an Excel table into a pandas DataFrame". ([documentation for read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html), and [for excel_file](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html?highlight=excelfile#pandas.ExcelFile))

I'm seeing answers here on SO that uses either, w/o addressing the difference. Also, a Google search didn't produce a result that discusses this issue.

WRT my testing, these seem equivalent:

```
path = "test/dummydata.xlsx"
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = xl.parse("dummydata")  # sheet name
```

and

```
path = "test/dummydata.xlsx" 
df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(path, sheetname=0)
```

other than the fact that the latter saves me a line, is there a difference between the two, and is there a reason to use either one?

Thanks!

Comment: doesn't really save you a line either, because: df = pd.ExcelFile(path).parse("dummydata")

Comment: Great question. This is the kind of question that I think makes a positive impact on aspiring coders.

Answer (score 69):

There's no particular difference beyond the syntax. Technically, `ExcelFile` is a class and `read_excel` is a function. In either case, the actual parsing is handled by the `_parse_excel` method defined within `ExcelFile`.

In earlier versions of pandas, [`read_excel`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.12.0/pandas/io/excel.py#L16) consisted entirely of a single statement (other than comments):

```
return ExcelFile(path_or_buf,kind=kind).parse(sheetname=sheetname,
                                              kind=kind, **kwds)
```

And [`ExcelFile.parse`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.12.0/pandas/io/excel.py#L81) didn't do much more than call `ExcelFile._parse_excel`.

In recent versions of pandas, [`read_excel`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/io/excel.py#L213) ensures that it has an `ExcelFile` object (and creates one if it doesn't), and then calls the `_parse_excel` method directly:

```
if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)

return io._parse_excel(...)
```

and with the updated (and unified) parameter handling, [`ExcelFile.parse`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/io/excel.py#L302) really is just the single statement:

```
return self._parse_excel(...)
```

That is why the docs for `ExcelFile.parse` now say

> Equivalent to read_excel(ExcelFile, ...) See the read_excel docstring for more info on accepted parameters

As for [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560203/95852) which claims that `ExcelFile.parse` is faster in a loop, that really just comes down to whether you are creating the `ExcelFile` object from scratch every time. You could certainly create your `ExcelFile` once, outside the loop, and pass *that* to `read_excel` inside your loop:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
for name in xl.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xl, name)
```

This would be equivalent to

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
for name in xl.sheet_names:
    df = xl.parse(name)
```

If your loop involves different *paths* (in other words, you are reading many different workbooks, not just multiple sheets within a single workbook), then you can't get around having to create a brand-new `ExcelFile` instance for each path anyway, and then once again, both `ExcelFile.parse` and `read_excel` will be equivalent (and equally slow).

Comment: Typo: `ExcelFile.sheetnames` should be `ExcelFile.sheet_names`

Comment: @grisaitis - Thanks, fixed!

Comment: To open a workbook using `ExcelFile` followed by parsing of specific worksheets, the solution benefits from the use of the `engine` parameter since `xlrd` 2.0 resp. `pandas` 1.2.0 (Dec 2020). Example: `xls = pd.ExcelFile(path,engine='xlrd')`, `df = xls.parse(sheet_name=sheetname)` ; or `xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path,engine='openpyxl')`, `df = xlsx.parse(sheet_name=sheetname)`

Answer (score 14):

`ExcelFile.parse` is faster.

Suppose you are reading dataframes in a loop.
With `ExcelFile.parse` you just pass the `Excelfile` object(`xl` in your case). So the excel sheet is just loaded once and you use this to get your dataframes.
In case of Read_Excel you pass the path instead of `Excelfile` object. So essentially every time the workbook is loaded again. Makes a mess if your workbook has loads of sheets and tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: You don't have to pass a path to `read_excel`. You could also pass an `ExcelFile` object, in which case they really are just equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

I believe Pandas first implementation of excel used the two step process, but then added the one step process called read_excel.  Probably left the first one in because folks were already using it