# How to load unstructured excel spreadsheet into pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am familiar with how to load an excel spreadsheet into a pandas dataframe. However, that assumes that the spreadsheet itself has well-defined columns and rows. I have 1 excel sheet which contains multiple tables and each table has different number of rows and columns. There is also some text along with tables in this same sheet. Any suggestions on how to get this loaded into pandas? Thanks.

Comment: parse it with another 3rd party library then throw it into a DataFrame, can we get some sample data or something?

Comment: I want to do it programmatically, ideally without any other 3rd party library use, if possible. Please find the sample data here: https://ufile.io/5novd

Answer (score 0):

pandas support many data format.

1. use `pd.read_excel`, it's read excel spreadsheet file(.xlsx)
2. export spreadsheet to csv and use `pd.read_csv`. I enjoy using this method.
3. use `pd.ExcelFile` to load, it's looks alike method 1. but it's faster see also [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474693/excelfile-vs-read-excel-in-pandas)

Comment: thanks, yes, I have already tried the pd.read_excel. But how to use it to parse an excel sheet which has multiple tables with inconsistent structure? Please see the sample data provided at  https://ufile.io/5novd

Comment: well, i recommend splitting it into several spreadsheets. It is difficult to handle various structures in Pandas. In your file, row[2:7] can be a single pandas DataFrame. After load multiple structures, concat or handle your data!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/excel', engine='openpyxl')
records = df.to_dict('records')
```

Then create a parser to read the `records` line by line. Match the `keys` with field name and extract corresponding/adjacent information.

On top of it, I have written a custom logic to handle different excel formats:

```
if os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower() == '.xls':
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='xlrd')
    except xlrd.biffh.XLRDError:
        df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl')
elif os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower() == '.xlsx':
    df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl')
else:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='odf')
```