# Pandas read excel: XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Also there existing already several questions on this topic with solutions:

[Pandas cannot open an Excel (.xlsx) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-an-excel-xlsx-file)

[xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254535/xlrd-biffh-xlrderror-excel-xlsx-file-not-supported)

I am working with `python 3.9` in visual studio code with the packages:

```
xlrd                    2.0.1
pandas                  1.1.5
openpyxl                3.1.2
```

when I am running the command:

```
mapping = pd.read_excel('mapping/mapping.xlsx', dtype=str, engine='openpyxl')
```

or:

```
mapping = pd.read_excel('mapping/mapping.xlsx', dtype=str)
```

it both gives the error:

> XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

The solutions provided in the similar questions don't help me here.

Comment: specifying the engine should have worked, can you confirm that the changes were saved before testing? As a workaround, you could downgrade `xlrd` to a version where `xlsx` is supported, but it should be noted that the author of `xlrd` explicitly discourages doing so in [a comment under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65251042/21169587) for security reasons.

Comment: the changes are saved before testing, and I don't want to downgrade my xlrd version

Comment: Have you tried only `pd.ExcelFile('mapping/mapping.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')` and then parse it to `str`? Related [stackoverflow: ExcelFile vs. read_excel in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474693/excelfile-vs-read-excel-in-pandas).

Comment: @Memristor same error

Comment: If you are trying this on a jupyter notebook maybe you should restart the kernel, just to rule out previous attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to `pandas 1.4.2` solved the error with the command:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas==1.42
```