# What is the difference between pd.ExcelFile and pd.read_excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Problem: I have a main data folder with subfolders. Each subfolder has excel files in it with the exactly same format. I'm reading a sheet called "test" from each excel file. I provide the absolute path to the main data folder. Using os.walk, os.path.join and os.listdir to iterate over the subfolders and read excel files.

Using pandas, I tried both pd.ExcelFile and pd.read_excel.

Question: pd.ExcelFile gives a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error" but pd.read_excel works fine. Why does the former throw a relative path error but pd.read_excel does not?

Comment: This is probably a difference in your own path handling, not a difference between `pandas.ExcelFile` and `pandas.read_excel`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExcelFile Vs. read\_excel in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474693/excelfile-vs-read-excel-in-pandas)